# Using other programming languages for malware against EDR?

Tags: malware, windows, virus, antivirus, programming

As an example, one of the most basic malware to inject into a process to get a C2 beacon goes like this:

```
Get Handle of a process -> VirtualAllocEx -> WriteProcessMemory -> CreateRemoteThread
```

Now writing this in C/C++ is quite native as it can easily communicate with WinAPI. Are there any benefits in writing this in another programming language such as Golang or Rust to fight against EDR, not just an AV with static analysis checks? More specifically EDRs that are hooking and calling `JMP` to those WinAPI calls?

My question comes from the rise of .NET and C# with a lot of use cases such as using LOLBAS csc.exe to compile on machine or `execute-assembly` to load .NET assemblies in unmanaged codespace or process. However, this still use WinAPI by using P/Invoke (and now D/Invoke).

1. Are there any benefits in using other programming language to call WinAPI function to fight against EDR?
2. Are there any other ways of creating malware (e.g. dropper) besides calling WinAPI?
3. Like with .NET and C#, will there be a new rise in existing (other) languages such as Go or Rust.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers inline:

1. No. Ex: If you are calling `WriteProcessMemory` from any kind of language C++, Python, Rust, it will internally call `NtWriteProcessMemory` (ntdll). You may be able to avoid some basic static analysis if you use python, c#, rust to call winapi, but you can do the same in C++ using `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`.
2. Yes, there are many frameworks like Metaspolit, C2, Powersploit, Empire, etc. that give you options for creating droppers in multiple languages.
3. Rise in Languages for ?? I'm assuming you mean more malware being developed in different languages? Yes, that is possible. But there is a catch :

- If you are writing malware specifically for a targeted attack, then yes writing the malware in other languages makes sense, provided you know that your target has the required runtime libs present to run the malware.
- If you are writing malware that you want to infect at a larger scale, it will be better to write in C/C++ because in those cases you don't need the target to install too many things.